# Using Ruby / Nokogiri to parse randomized class names

Tags: ruby, xpath, css-selectors, html-parsing, nokogiri

I've been doing calculations by hand when it comes to the remaining percentage of the US Presidential election votes in various states. With so many updates and states – this is getting tiring. So why not automate the process?

Here's what I'm looking at:

[image]

The problem is that the class names have been randomized. For example, here's the one I'm interested in:
`<td class="jsx-3768461732 votes votes-row">2,450,186</td>`

Playing around in irb, I tried to use a wildcard on "votes votes-row", since this only appears when I need it in the doc:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.politico.com/2020-election/results/georgia/"))
votes = doc.css("[td*='votes-row']")
```

...which yields no results (`=> []`)

What am I doing wrong and how to fix? I'm ok with xpath – I just want to make sure changes made elsewhere in the doc don't affect finding these elements.

Comment: If you view source of https://www.politico.com/2020-election/results/georgia/ and find in there, there doesn't appear to be a votes-row result. Maybe these classes are added with JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a better way but...

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.politico.com/2020-election/results/georgia/"))
votes = doc.css('tr[class*="candidate-row"]').map { |row| row.css('td').map { |cell| cell.content } }
biden_row = votes.find_index { |row| row[0] =~ /biden/i }
trump_row = votes.find_index { |row| row[0] =~ /trump/i }
biden_votes = votes[biden_row][1].split('%')[1]
trump_votes = votes[trump_row][1].split('%')[1]
```

Edit: from the HTML source the relevant table looks like:

```
<table class="jsx-1526769828 candidate-table">
  <thead class="jsx-3554868417 table-head">
    <tr class="jsx-3554868417">
      <th class="table-header jsx-3554868417 candidate-name">
        <h5 class="jsx-3554868417">Candidate</h5>
      </th>
      <th class="table-header jsx-3554868417 percent">
        <h5 class="jsx-3554868417">Pct.</h5>
      </th>
      <th class="table-header jsx-3554868417 vote-bar"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="jsx-2085888330 table-head">
    <tr class="jsx-2677388595 candidate-row">
      <td class="jsx-3948343365 candidate-name name-row">
        <div class="jsx-1912693590 name-only candidate-short-name">Biden</div>
        <div class="jsx-3948343365 candidate-party-tag">
          <div class="jsx-1420258095 party-label dem">dem</div>
        </div>
        <div class="jsx-3948343365 candidate-winner-check"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="jsx-3830922081 percent percent-row">
        <div class="candidate-percent-only jsx-3830922081">49.4%</div>
        <div class="candidate-votes-next-to-percent jsx-3830922081">2,450,193</div>
      </td>
      <td class="jsx-3458171655 vote-bar vote-bar-row">
        <div style="width:49.4%" class="jsx-3458171655 bar dem"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="jsx-2677388595 candidate-row">
      <td class="jsx-3948343365 candidate-name name-row">
        <div class="jsx-1912693590 name-only candidate-short-name">Trump*</div>
        <div class="jsx-3948343365 candidate-party-tag">
          <div class="jsx-1420258095 party-label gop">gop</div>
        </div>
        <div class="jsx-3948343365 candidate-winner-check"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="jsx-3830922081 percent percent-row">
        <div class="candidate-percent-only jsx-3830922081">49.4%</div>
        <div class="candidate-votes-next-to-percent jsx-3830922081">2,448,635</div>
      </td>
      <td class="jsx-3458171655 vote-bar vote-bar-row">
        <div style="width:49.4%" class="jsx-3458171655 bar gop"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So you could probably use the candidate-votes-next-to-percent to get this value. e.g.:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.politico.com/2020-election/results/georgia/"))
votes = doc.css('tr[class*="candidate-row"]').map do |row|
  [
    row.css('div[class*="candidate-short-name"]').first.content,
    row.css('div[class*="candidate-votes-next-to-percent"]').first.content
  ]
end
# => [["Biden", "2,450,193"], ["Trump*", "2,448,635"]]
```

Comment: So was javascript not a factor after all?

Comment: doc.css('td[class*="votes"]').size is 0, and votes-row doesn't appear in the source, so I guess those classes must be being added in JS. candidate-row does appear in the source though, so you can use it with Nokogiri